# Is it possible to add Python code, which can access files on the machine in which it is running & mail them, to an Angular2 Web Application?

Tags: python, angular

I have a running Angular2 app which has currently been hosted on Firebase. 
And then I have a python (2.7) code using which a user can mail some file (present locally on his computer) to some person, both having gmail accounts.

I tested this code and it works fine on my laptop.

My question is, how can I include this python code with my existing Angular2 Web application so that it runs the same way as it runs on a computer, and sends a mail with some attachments?

Here is my Python code :

```
# Python code to illustrate Sending mail with attachments
# from your Gmail account 

# libraries to be imported
import os
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders

fromaddr = "sender@gmail.com"
toaddr = "recipient@gmail.com"

# instance of MIMEMultipart
msg = MIMEMultipart()

# storing the senders email address  
msg['From'] = fromaddr

# storing the receivers email address 
msg['To'] = toaddr

# storing the subject 
msg['Subject'] = "Trial Attachments"

# string to store the body of the mail
body = "Just checking if Images would go"

# attach the body with the msg instance
msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

# open the file to be sent 
#filename = "tash.png"
folder = os.listdir("/path/to-some/folder/")
for f in folder:
    filename = f 
    attachment = open("/path/to-some/folder/%s" %(f), "rb")

    # instance of MIMEBase and named as p
    p = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')

    # To change the payload into encoded form
    p.set_payload((attachment).read())

    # encode into base64
    encoders.encode_base64(p)

    p.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" %    filename)

    # attach the instance 'p' to instance 'msg'
    msg.attach(p)

# creates SMTP session
s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)

# start TLS for security
s.starttls()

# Authentication
s.login(fromaddr, "######")

# Converts the Multipart msg into a string
text = msg.as_string()

# sending the mail
try:
    s.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
    print "Successfully sent email"
except:
    print "Failed to send mail"

# terminating the session
s.quit()
```